# How to find the root of a binary tree?

Tags: database

> Find the root of each of the following binary trees:
> a) tree with postorder traversal FCBDG
> b) tree with preorder traversal IBCDFEN
> c) tree with inorder traversal CBIDFGE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a. tree with postorder traversal: FCBDG Postorder**

Inorder (Left, Root, Right) Preorder (Root, Left, Right) Postorder (Left, Right, Root)